# Transaction context of the caller is NOT suspended when entering an autonomous PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions, oracle11gr2

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i36056) autonomous transaction should suspend its calling transaction, BUT it's not functioning as described in oracle docs, instead aoutonomous transaction executes independently, that means parallely. That's my situation. I have package with several procedures, one of them is declared with `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`, something like this:

```
PROCEDURE test1
IS
BEGIN
  test2;
  INSERT INTO <mytable> VALUES(<values>);
END;

PROCEDURE test2
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO <maytable2> VALUES(<values>);
END;
```

When I call autonomous procedure from non-autonomous procedure they execute parallely, but in fact they should execute in given order.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to silve this?

Comment: How are you determining they're executing in parallel? `test1` will wait until `test2` completes before performing its insert. What are you seeing that suggests otherwise? What exactly needs to be solved?

Comment: No, `test1` doesn't wait until `test2` completes. In reality, it depends how much work is done, this means if  `INSERT INTO <maytable2> VALUES(<values>);`  takes too long to complete than  `INSERT INTO <mytable> VALUES(<values>);`  then we can see that `INSERT INTO <mytable> VALUES(<values>);`  completes first and this is not what documentation says

Comment: I've added an answer demonstrating the reverse - too long for a comment. If you have a reproducible test case that shows the behaviour you describe please add it; at the moment you're stating something that doesn't appear to be correct, without any evidence. What work is being done by `test2` when you see this?

Answer (score 1):

My testing disagrees with your assertion:

```
create table t1 (id number, ts timestamp);
create table t2 (id number, ts timestamp);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test2
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(10);
  INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(2, systimestamp);
  COMMIT;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1
IS
BEGIN
  test2;
  INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, systimestamp);
END;
/

exec test1;

select * from t1;
select * from t2;
```

Which gets:

```
table T1 created.
table T2 created.
PROCEDURE TEST2 compiled
PROCEDURE TEST1 compiled
anonymous block completed
        ID TS                         
---------- ----------------------------
         1 02-OCT-14 11.46.54.649925000 

        ID TS                         
---------- ----------------------------
         2 02-OCT-14 11.46.54.629156000
```

However long I make the sleep (well, up to 30 seconds anyway) this behaviour holds; even if I commit before the sleep in `test2`. I repeated this with the procedures in a package and the same thing happens. The insert from `test2` is always happening before the insert from `test1`.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon this so I'm six years late :), but Oracle docs (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/autotransaction_pragma.htm#LNPLS01302) clearly state that:

> When an autonomous routine is invoked, **the main transaction is
> suspended**. The autonomous transaction is fully independent of the
> main transaction: they share no locks, resources, or commit
> dependencies. The autonomous transaction does not affect the main
> transaction.

and Alex Poole example demonstrates that